# Why does my visual studio prompt me to install sql when I already have it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223863/pete2k) post. It is perfectly ok to try and set up an .mdf database inside the Asp.net App_Data folder and let it attach to an instance of sql server (the normal one). However when I try and do this I get an error from visual studio saying I must install Sql server express 2005 or 2008.

[image]

However, this is really confusing as Ive been told I should be able to do this on a normal sql server installation which I cant....Any ideas why Im having trouble?

NOTE :  I have set the instance name in the options to be sqlexpress in visual studio options for database, and I have an alias on my sql server that works (I can connect with management studio)...

Comment: You linked to your user profile instead of an actual post